# How to append smaller DataFrame to another DataFrame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, append

I have a single DataFrame that needs to be sent to a Quality Test API that should return another DataFrame.

But unfortunately the API is not accepting the DataFrame as a whole and hence I am slicing it row by row and sending it to the API.

Hence I am getting single row DataFrames with each request.
Can someone tell me how I can keep appending these single rows to a larger Data Frame?

Comment: just take them back and set them equal to a variable: `x<-rbind(old_df, new_line_df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can append data frames to each other using `bind_rows` from the `dplyr` package.

```
df1 = data.frame(number = c(1, 2, 3, 4), 
                 name=c("Alice", "Bob", "Charlie", "Donna")
df2 = data.frame(number = c(5), name=c("Eve"))
df3 = bind_rows(df1, df2) #df3 has all five rows.
```